# How can I export a database from phpMyAdmin when the "Export" tab is missing?

Tags: mysql, backup, export, phpmyadmin

My Webhost has disappeared, possibly because the company has gone out of business. I no longer have access to cloud-based backups which my host created on a daily basis, however I still have access to phpMyAdmin (version 3.5.4).

Within phpMyAdmin, the "Export" tab is missing. I also can't create and copy a database within the "Operations" tab. Is there an alternative way I can do a database dump of all the DBs on the server, e.g. from the SQL tab?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `FILE` privilege you can, table by table, use SELECT ...  [`INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html) queries  and download your data from those.